# how to send POST(javascript) to laravel blade file?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, http-post

I made a webcam page in Laravel5.
I would like to send POST(javascript, WEBCAMjs) to crop.blade.php(laravel).

My code works well when run with only php.
   => form.setAttribute("action", "crop.php");
However, if I try to send it to laravel(crop.blade.php), it returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException.
   => form.setAttribute("action", "crop.blade.php");

How can I solve this problem?
thanks for your help in advance!

```
Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
        var obj1 = data_uri
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("charset", "UTF-8");
        form.setAttribute("method", "Post");
        #form.setAttribute("action", "crop.php");
        form.setAttribute("action", "crop.blade.php");
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "raw");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", obj1);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);

        var url ="crop"

        var status = "toolbar=no,directories=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,menubar=no,width=1240, height=1200, top=0,left=20"

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Missing CSRF field/token?

Answer (score 0):

It will be the routing. If you go to your `web.php` file, you will see the route that you are loading for the page. It might look like the following:

```
Route::get('crop', function () {
    return view('crop');
});
```

You also need the following to allow post requests

```
Route::post('crop', function () {
    // Logic for the post request
});
```

Obviously it would be better to use controllers instead of closures, but that's the general idea.

Comment: I'm soory, Actually, I tried that method already.  But the result was still MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Comment: What is the contents of your `web.php` file? I would imagine that you would need to change your JavaScript code from `form.setAttribute("action", "crop.blade.php")` to `form.setAttribute("action", "/crop")`. The URL should be the endpoint, not the `blade.php` file.